# java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Expected URL scheme 'http' or 'https' but no colon was found

Tags: android, crash, okhttp, firebase-remote-config, zendesk

I have such crash on prod, but can't understand how that could happen. I am init Zendesk SDK with correct links that has https schemes, but still get this error on prod. When we where testing this - everything was fine. Can it be related to some firebase issue? I am getting this urls fro firebase remote config, but I have also that versions of urls hardcoded in local strings, and if remote confing fetching fails - I am using defaults.

I am using:

```
api group: 'com.zendesk', name: 'support', version: '5.0.1' //Zendesk SDK for Android
com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.7.2
com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.7.2
com.squareup.retrofit2:adapter-rxjava2:2.7.2
com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:4.4.0
```

Crash report:

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to create application com.myApplication.application.MyApp: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Expected URL scheme 'http' or 'https' but no colon was found
   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:6079)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1300(ActivityThread.java:207)
   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1758)
   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6898)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
   at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:537)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
```

Second part:

```
Caused by java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Expected URL scheme 'http' or 'https' but no colon was found
   at okhttp3.HttpUrl$Builder.parse$okhttp(HttpUrl.kt:1261)
   at okhttp3.HttpUrl$Companion.get(HttpUrl.kt:1634)
   at okhttp3.HttpUrl.get(:2)
   at retrofit2.Retrofit$Builder.baseUrl(Retrofit.java:492)
   at zendesk.core.ZendeskNetworkModule.provideCoreRetrofit(ZendeskNetworkModule.java:220)
   at zendesk.core.ZendeskNetworkModule_ProvideCoreRetrofitFactory.provideCoreRetrofit(ZendeskNetworkModule_ProvideCoreRetrofitFactory.java:43)
   at zendesk.core.ZendeskNetworkModule_ProvideCoreRetrofitFactory.get(ZendeskNetworkModule_ProvideCoreRetrofitFactory.java:32)
   at zendesk.core.ZendeskNetworkModule_ProvideCoreRetrofitFactory.get(ZendeskNetworkModule_ProvideCoreRetrofitFactory.java:11)
   at dagger.internal.DoubleCheck.get(DoubleCheck.java:47)
   at zendesk.core.ZendeskProvidersModule_ProvideBlipsServiceFactory.get(ZendeskProvidersModule_ProvideBlipsServiceFactory.java:22)
   at zendesk.core.ZendeskProvidersModule_ProvideBlipsServiceFactory.get(ZendeskProvidersModule_ProvideBlipsServiceFactory.java:9)
   at dagger.internal.DoubleCheck.get(DoubleCheck.java:47)
   at zendesk.core.ZendeskProvidersModule_ProviderZendeskBlipsProviderFactory.get(ZendeskProvidersModule_ProviderZendeskBlipsProviderFactory.java:45)
   at zendesk.core.ZendeskProvidersModule_ProviderZendeskBlipsProviderFactory.get(ZendeskProvidersModule_ProviderZendeskBlipsProviderFactory.java:9)
   at dagger.internal.DoubleCheck.get(DoubleCheck.java:47)
   at zendesk.core.ZendeskProvidersModule_ProviderBlipsCoreProviderFactory.get(ZendeskProvidersModule_ProviderBlipsCoreProviderFactory.java:22)
   at zendesk.core.ZendeskProvidersModule_ProviderBlipsCoreProviderFactory.get(ZendeskProvidersModule_ProviderBlipsCoreProviderFactory.java:8)
   at dagger.internal.DoubleCheck.get(DoubleCheck.java:47)
   at zendesk.core.ZendeskApplicationModule_ProvideZendeskFactory.get(ZendeskApplicationModule_ProvideZendeskFactory.java:44)
   at zendesk.core.ZendeskApplicationModule_ProvideZendeskFactory.get(ZendeskApplicationModule_ProvideZendeskFactory.java:8)
   at dagger.internal.DoubleCheck.get(DoubleCheck.java:47)
   at zendesk.core.DaggerZendeskApplicationComponent.zendeskShadow(DaggerZendeskApplicationComponent.java:251)
   at zendesk.core.Zendesk.init(Zendesk.java:81)
   at zendesk.core.Zendesk.init(Zendesk.java:66)
   at com.myApplication.application.App.initializeZendeskSdk(App.java:161)
   at com.myApplication.application.App.onCreate(App.java:101)
   at com.myApplication.application.MyApp.onCreate(MyApp.java:35)
   at android.app.Instrumentation.callApplicationOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1165)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:6074)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1300(ActivityThread.java:207)
   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1758)
   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6898)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
   at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:537)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue was in that my firebase remote config in 3% of times failed initialization, and somehow it returned empty values of zendesk host url. So I moved my code to the place when remote config fully initialized and take it in try/catch block to avoid app crashing just in case. Using Zendesk android SDK 5.0.1.

```
private void initializeZendeskSdk() {
        try {
            Zendesk.INSTANCE.init(context, firebaseRemoteConfigManager.getZendeskHostUrl(),
                    firebaseRemoteConfigManager.getZendeskApplicationId(),
                    firebaseRemoteConfigManager.getZendeskOAuthClientId());

            Logger.setLoggable(true);
            Support.INSTANCE.init(Zendesk.INSTANCE);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            if (e.getMessage() != null)
                FirebaseCrashlytics.getInstance().log(e.getMessage());
        }
    }
```